# Creating a border line in scatterplot points R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a black borderline of points in the following plot. `color = "black"` in following code colors every point by black.

```
whittaker_base_plot() +
  labs(
    title = "Locations by Biomes") +
  # add the temperature - precipitation data points
  geom_point(data = extractions, 
             aes(x = temperature, 
                 y = precipitation, 
                 color = Group,
                 shape=model), 
             stroke = 0.1,
             size   = 6,
             #color = "black" # colors every point with black
             alpha  = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right your problem, I think you need to set the shape property of the points, so you can color a boderline on each point. When you set shape to 21, this is 21th model of shape. You can read more about this here:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-point-shapes

In this model, all points in your plot have a "color" property, which is the color of the border of your point, and, a "fill" property, which is the color inside the point.

```r
whittaker_base_plot() +
  labs(
    title = "Locations by Biomes") +
  # add the temperature - precipitation data points
  geom_point(data = extractions, 
             aes(x = temperature, 
                 y = precipitation,
                 fill = Group)), 
             stroke = 0.1,
             shape = 21,
             size   = 6,
             color = "black"
             alpha  = 0.5)
```

The obvious dowside of this, is that you can no longer represent the `model` variable in the `shape` property of your points. But anyway, the 21 shape model is the standard way to color a boderline over each point in ggplot2.

OBS: the `stroke` property sets the "size" or "width" of the boderlines painted in the points. So, `stroke = 0.1` might create a very thin boderline. So thin that you might not be able to see it. You might want to raise this stroke a bit.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, but  also want to have shape of points by "model"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
geom_point(data = extractions, 
             aes(x = temperature, 
                 y = precipitation, 
                 fill = Group,
                 shape=model), 
             stroke = 0.1,
             size   = 6,
             color = "black",
             pch = 21,
             alpha  = 0.5)
```

pch needs to be 21 or 22 to visualize the borders of points

Comment: Thanks ilFonta, your suggestion created a black borderline but removed the fill color.

Comment: Does it works for you? If yes could you please vote for my reply please?

Comment: No it didn't work, because it created the borderline but removed the fill color.